# Problem after using the wrong password no a Hive encrypted box

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I just wanted to confirm that this is the expected behavior (or at least, that it's known unexpected behavior). I've created a HiveDb that encrypts all of the boxes. I'm trying to create a function that allows for the cipher to be changed. And I'm testing with the following code:

```dart
/// Search using the original password    
final List<Resource> search2 = await fhirDbDao.find(password1, resourceType: R4ResourceType.Patient, id: '1');

/// correct
expect(saved1, search2[0]);

/// updates the password/cipher on the encrypted boxes
await fhirDbDao.updatePw(password1, password2);

/// returns an empty list as we're now using the wrong password
final List<Resource> search3 = await fhirDbDao.find(password1, resourceType: R4ResourceType.Patient, id: '1');

/// correct
expect(true, search3.isEmpty);

/// also returns an empty list
final List<Resource> search4 = await fhirDbDao.find(password2, resourceType: R4ResourceType.Patient, id: '1');

/// throws an error
expect(saved1, search4[0]);
```

Now, what's interesting is if I comment out search3 then search4 performs as expected, so I believe I'm updating the encryption properly. So as I said, I just wanted to ask if this is the expected behavior. And if it is, is there a way to open an encrypted box using the correct password/cipher after someone has attempted to open it using the wrong one?